# Protractor Cucumber - CompositeParserException (Windows 7 X64)

Tags: protractor, webdriver, cucumber

Hi there: I'm facing the next issue when I try to run my feature.
I'm new on Protractor.

```
    C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\parser.js:21
          throw e;
          ^
CompositeParserException: Parser errors:
(1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '"use strict";'
(3:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {'
(4:3): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'value: true'
(5:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '});'
(6:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'exports.default = run;'
(8:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'var _ = _interopRequireDefault(require("./"));'
(10:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'var _verror = _interopRequireDefault(require("verror"));'
(12:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }'
(14:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw); } }'
(16:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var self = this, args = arguments; return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { var gen = fn.apply(self, args); function _next(value) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value); } function _throw(err) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err); } _next(undefined); }); }; }'
(18:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'function exitWithError(error) {'
path: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\run.js
    at Function.Errors.CompositeParserException.create (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\errors.js:27:13)
    at addError (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:88:45)
    at matchTokenAt_0 (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:261:5)
    at matchToken (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:149:14)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:72:15)
    at C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\parser.js:18:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\parser.js:12:22)
    at Object.getFeatures (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\runtime.js:39:35)
    at Object.start (C:\Users\pc\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\runtime.js:11:27)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have installed the next ones:

Protractor version 5.4.2 
Node version 10.16.3
NPM 6.9.0

This is my conf.js file

```
exports.config = {

framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: 'protractor-cucumber-framework',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
baseUrl: 'https://www.afphabitat.cl/portalPrivado_FIXWeb/public/login.htm',
ignoreSynchronization: true,
getPageTimeout: 60000,
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,

specs: ['features/**/*.feature'],
cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['step_defs/**/*.steps.js'],
    tags: ['@wip'],
    monochrome: true,
    strict: true,
    plugin: "json",
    format: 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json',
    resultJsonOutputFile: 'e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'
},

multiCapabilities:
    [{
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--start-maximized']
        }
    },
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox',
            args: ['--no-sandbox','--start-maximized']
        }],
/*capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
        binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
        args: ['--no-sandbox','--start-maximized']
    }
},*/
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
//    print: function() {}
}
}
```

Feature file is the next: No created stepdefs yet:

```
    Feature: Login to AFP Habitat

  As a user of AFP Habitat,
  I want to login to the page
  So I log with my credentials

  @wip
  Scenario: Login successful

    Given I open the url "<https://www.afphabitat.cl/portalPrivado_FIXWeb/public/login.htm>"
    When proceed to enter my username as "<666666666>"
    And proceed to enter my password as "<999999999>"
    Then I have been logged in successfully
```

By other hand, I'm using Webstorm IDE in Windows 7 X64.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with the next action:

I have to make a change in the Run/Debug configurations:

change the **Cucumber Package** from `WebstormProjects\my_project\node_modules\cucumber` (version 5.1.0)

Now I can run the feature, but I'm getting the next exception:

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "cucumber";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```